# know which algorithm is used, program written in vb6

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, networking, cypher

If I know original text : "N.B.MARKETING PVT. LTD." 
which encodes to :

```
 "rFnJa‡‰¢ iv«¯ŸcŠ›••Š«†›‚‹v¥nZr"
```

how I can identify which algorithm is used?

Comment: Do you want to decipher other strings encoded with this algorithm? What is your end goal?

Comment: In general, you can't. So unless there are some extra information you are not telling, it is impossible.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to decipher it or do you want to know the encryption technique used?

Comment: You wants to know the protocol and algorithm used to produce `rFnJa‡‰¢ iv«¯ŸcŠ›••Š«†›‚‹v¥nZr`. I don't think its possible otherwise whats the purpose of encoding.

Comment: so there is no way out to decipher this or to know which algorithm is used in encryption.

Comment: basically i want to know encryption technique used in this. @RahulTripathi

Comment: It might be possible if you're able to decompile the code. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the program binary that performs the encoding, you could try to use this plugin to analyze the binary:

http://www.hexblog.com/?p=27

**Edit:** Also, you can just decompile the program (using dotPeek or ILSpy or Reflector) and look through its code. You should be able to pinpoint the place in the code which contains the encryption logic. If it's not obvious for you what the code is doing, we could help you further.